# How to receive json with same KEY i.e. "data" but different VALUE in every response with Retrofit 2.0 and Gson in android application.

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am using json web services in my android application. To get json I am using Retrofit 2.0 and Gson.

These are the json responses that I am getting.

**Response 1:**

```
{
  "Status": true,
  "Message": null,
  "Data": {
    "User_Name": "sanky",
    "Name": "Sanket"
  }
}
```

**Response 2:**

```
{
  "Status": true,
  "Message": null,
  "Data": {
    "Id": "c2010",
    "Name": "Sanket",
    "Email": "sanky@gmail.com",
    "Address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
    "Gender": "male",
    "Phone": {
      "Mobile": "+91 0000000000",
      "Home": "00 000000",
      "Office": "00 000000"
    }
  }
}
```

For this purpose I have created POJO for both these responses using jsonschema2pojo.com
But I am not being able to receive both these responses in a single project. Problem I am getting is that how to receive response for key "Data" in single project when both responses have different structure?

Any help appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you combine both the data inside one POJO because it will only increase one more element and you can always check for `null` while using this data.

Comment: @Himanshu - but I also have many other responses for "data" key. Not these only two

Comment: oh okay then you can manually parse the data by yourself. Based on the kind of data you can create POJOs

Comment: k. I will try it. Thanks If stuck at somewhere, I will get back to you

Comment: sure dude try it, if you can change the backend response try doing that too have a extra parameter `type` outside `data` object which can tell what kind of data is coming with `Data`.

Comment: backend code already developed now. So these people are not changing the code... So Its completely on my side... unfortunately

Comment: @Himanshu - Can you provide some code sample to me so that I can understand shortly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121811/discussion-between-himanshu1496-and-sanket).

Answer (score 0):

Cut the hands of your server programmer, lol) But you can also make your custom GSon parser or parse response manually.

Comment: Can you explain how to make custom GSon parser or parse response manually? Because I am new to android. Don't know in depth

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Comment: Thanks alex. Seems to be usefull. I am going to read these. If stuck at somewhere, I will get back to you